# How can I remove multiple objects bound with each other from database?

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony4

I am trying to remove() the Book that contains multiple pages. When I delete the book, it is not present in database anymore while its pages aren't removed. What I would like to do is to remove a book together with pages that are bound with it.

What I tried already is the following, but the framework shows me no error.

```
/**
* @Route("/site/delete/{idSite}", name="delete")
*/
public function delete(Request $request, $idSite){


    $liste_books=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Book::class)->findOneBy(['idSite'=>$idSite]);


    $liste_pages=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Page::class)->findBy(['idSite'=>$idSite]);


    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $em->remove($liste_books, $liste_pages);    
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('site');
```

Comment: I mostly use `doctrine-odm` but ORM should have a `cascade` options, when you map your relationship between your Entities. Once this option is set correctly, removing an Entity should remove the related one too.

Comment: If a Page is owned exclusively by a Book, then you can set `orphanRemoval=true` in the annotation for the pages parameter within you Book entity. When you remove a book, all pages would be removed as well. See the [docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal).

Comment: Also, you try to pass too many arguments to remove method
https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/latest/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.html#method_remove